# java Android - how can I make WebView transparent for android 2.x?

Tags: android, webview, transparent

I need a WebView to be transparent, but can't find solution

I've found only

```
webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

, but this is only for Honeycomb and older and I need my App to work on 2.x also.
None of the solutions I've found on stackoverflow are working- webView is still white.

Can anyone tell me what's working for sure for pre-Honeycomb versions?

maybe I should change something in html as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This worked for me : myWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

OR add as part of html 
here is my code snip :

```
String css = "<head><style >* {word-wrap: break-word;margin:0;padding:0;font-size:15px; text-align:justify;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}</style></head>";

myWebView.loadData(css, "text/html", null);
myWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: import android.graphics.Color;

Comment: did u import properly

Comment: then try apply {background: transparent} as html with it

Comment: body { font-family: Times New Roman; color: #000000; background-color: transparent;} is it right ? I'm just zero in html, I may added it wrong. it's inside <style>

Comment: my reputation is low for chat

Comment: this room is open public

Comment: it says I have to have 20 reputation to talk here

Answer (score 0):

I had written a helper method to do that and it seems to work the majority of the time, setting the background color to transparent for all versions and changing the layer type where available...

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static void clearWebViewBackground (final WebView webView) {
    webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00FFFFFF);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2234594 what device are you testing on?